# ITK with QT: undefined reference vnl_vector in metadataobject.cxx

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries, undefined-reference, itk

I am trying to compile a Qt project that uses ITK but I am receiving linker errors (see below) from the ITK libraries. I am running on Ubuntu 16.04 and building with Qt 5.9.1. I compiled the ITK version 4.12.1 but I have also tried 4.13 as well as a pre-built version of 4.12.2 from a colleague. I have tried compiling with CMake 3.5 and later with CMake 3.10 but I get the same errors for all of these combinations.

I have generated the list of libraries that I include in my Qt project using the command `lorder * | tsort` while in the `lib` folder of the ITK build. This should generate the correct order of include libraries right?

The compiler is complaining about not finding `vnl_vector`, but I checked the list of linked libraries and `-litkvnl` as well as `-litkvnl_algo` are in there and above `-lITKCommon` which seems to be the problem.

Below I have provided the compile errors as well as the .pri file in which I link to the libraries. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Error message:

```
//usr/local/lib/libITKCommon-4.12.a(itkMetaDataObject.cxx.o): In function `itk::MetaDataObject<itk::Array<char> >::~MetaDataObject()':
itkMetaDataObject.cxx:(.text._ZN3itk14MetaDataObjectINS_5ArrayIcEEED2Ev[_ZN3itk14MetaDataObjectINS_5ArrayIcEEED5Ev]+0x2a): undefined reference to `vnl_vector<char>::~vnl_vector()'
//usr/local/lib/libITKCommon-4.12.a(itkMetaDataObject.cxx.o): In function `itk::MetaDataObject<itk::Array<int> >::~MetaDataObject()':
itkMetaDataObject.cxx:(.text._ZN3itk14MetaDataObjectINS_5ArrayIiEEED2Ev[_ZN3itk14MetaDataObjectINS_5ArrayIiEEED5Ev]+0x2a): undefined reference to `vnl_vector<int>::~vnl_vector()'
Makefile:249: recipe for target 'mesh2binary' failed
//usr/local/lib/libITKCommon-4.12.a(itkMetaDataObject.cxx.o): In function `itk::MetaDataObject<itk::Array<float> >::~MetaDataObject()':
itkMetaDataObject.cxx:(.text._ZN3itk14MetaDataObjectINS_5ArrayIfEEED2Ev[_ZN3itk14MetaDataObjectINS_5ArrayIfEEED5Ev]+0x2a): undefined reference to `vnl_vector<float>::~vnl_vector()'
//usr/local/lib/libITKCommon-4.12.a(itkMetaDataObject.cxx.o): In function `itk::MetaDataObject<itk::Array<char> >::SetMetaDataObjectValue(itk::Array<char> const&)':
itkMetaDataObject.cxx:(.text._ZN3itk14MetaDataObjectINS_5ArrayIcEEE22SetMetaDataObjectValueERKS2_[_ZN3itk14MetaDataObjectINS_5ArrayIcEEE22SetMetaDataObjectValueERKS2_]+0x26): undefined reference to `vnl_vector<char>::set_size(unsigned long)'
itkMetaDataObject.cxx:(.text._ZN3itk14MetaDataObjectINS_5ArrayIcEEE22SetMetaDataObjectValueERKS2_[_ZN3itk14MetaDataObjectINS_5ArrayIcEEE22SetMetaDataObjectValueERKS2_]+0x39): undefined reference to `vnl_vector<char>::operator=(vnl_vector<char> const&)'
//usr/local/lib/libITKCommon-4.12.a(itkMetaDataObject.cxx.o): In function `itk::MetaDataObject<itk::Array<int> >::SetMetaDataObjectValue(itk::Array<int> const&)':
itkMetaDataObject.cxx:(.text._ZN3itk14MetaDataObjectINS_5ArrayIiEEE22SetMetaDataObjectValueERKS2_[_ZN3itk14MetaDataObjectINS_5ArrayIiEEE22SetMetaDataObjectValueERKS2_]+0x26): undefined reference to `vnl_vector<int>::set_size(unsigned long)'
itkMetaDataObject.cxx:(.text._ZN3itk14MetaDataObjectINS_5ArrayIiEEE22SetMetaDataObjectValueERKS2_[_ZN3itk14MetaDataObjectINS_5ArrayIiEEE22SetMetaDataObjectValueERKS2_]+0x39): undefined reference to `vnl_vector<int>::operator=(vnl_vector<int> const&)'
//usr/local/lib/libITKCommon-4.12.a(itkMetaDataObject.cxx.o): In function `itk::MetaDataObject<itk::Array<float> >::SetMetaDataObjectValue(itk::Array<float> const&)':
itkMetaDataObject.cxx:(.text._ZN3itk14MetaDataObjectINS_5ArrayIfEEE22SetMetaDataObjectValueERKS2_[_ZN3itk14MetaDataObjectINS_5ArrayIfEEE22SetMetaDataObjectValueERKS2_]+0x26): undefined reference to `vnl_vector<float>::set_size(unsigned long)'
itkMetaDataObject.cxx:(.text._ZN3itk14MetaDataObjectINS_5ArrayIfEEE22SetMetaDataObjectValueERKS2_[_ZN3itk14MetaDataObjectINS_5ArrayIfEEE22SetMetaDataObjectValueERKS2_]+0x39): undefined reference to `vnl_vector<float>::operator=(vnl_vector<float> const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mesh2binary] Error 1
11:24:11: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project mesh2binary (kit: Desktop Qt 5.9.1 GCC 64bit2)
When executing step "Make"
```

.pri file which I include in my .pro file:

```
ITKDIR=/usr/local/ITK/InsightToolkit-4.12.1-Release/include/ITK-4.12
ITKLIB=/usr/local/ITK/InsightToolkit-4.12.1-Release/build/lib


VERSIONNUMBER=4.12

#Include ITK Headers
INCLUDEPATH += $${ITKDIR}

# ITK Libs
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKBiasCorrection-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKBioCell-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKDICOMParser-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKFEM-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOBMP-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOBioRad-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOCSV-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOGDCM-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOGE-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOGIPL-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOHDF5-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOJPEG-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOLSM-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOMRC-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOMesh-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOMeta-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIONIFTI-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIONRRD-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOPNG-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOSiemens-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOSpatialObjects-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOStimulate-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOTransformBase-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOTransformHDF5-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOTransformInsightLegacy-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOTransformMatlab-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOVTK-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKKLMRegionGrowing-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKLabelMap-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKMesh-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKOptimizers-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKOptimizersv4-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKPath-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKPolynomials-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKQuadEdgeMesh-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKSpatialObjects-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKStatistics-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKTransform-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKVNLInstantiation-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKVTK-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKVideoCore-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKVideoIO-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKWatersheds-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
#LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lhdf5
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkgdcmMEXD-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litknetlib-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litktestlib-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOTIFF-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKgiftiio-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKMetaIO-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKNrrdIO-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkpng-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOIPL-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOXML-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKTransformFactory-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkhdf5_cpp
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkNetlibSlatec-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkvnl_algo-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkgdcmMSFF-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkgdcmsocketxx-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litktiff-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKniftiio-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKIOImageBase-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkhdf5
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkvnl-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkv3p_netlib-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkgdcmDICT-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkgdcmcharls-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkgdcmuuid-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkgdcmopenjpeg-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkgdcmjpeg8-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkgdcmjpeg16-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkgdcmjpeg12-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkjpeg-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKznz-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKCommon-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkvcl-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkgdcmIOD-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litksys-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkdouble-conversion-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkgdcmDSED-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -lITKEXPAT-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkgdcmCommon-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
LIBS += -L$${ITKLIB} -litkzlib-$${VERSIONNUMBER}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to convert your project's build system into CMake. I do not advice build ITK with any other system than CMake. Since 2.8.10 it is quite stable, and if you even have a current version, there should be no problems.

Your CMakeLists.txt file would probably look similiar to this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
project(HelloWorldItkQt)
# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc and uic automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
# Find the Qt libraries
find_package(Qt5Gui)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package(Qt5Core)
#find and enable ITK
find_package(ITK)
include(${ITK_USE_FILE})
# Tell CMake to create the helloworld executable
add_executable(HelloWorldItkQt WIN32 mainwindow.h simpledialog.h mainwindow.cpp simpledialog.cpp main.cpp)

# Use the Widgets module from Qt 5.
target_link_libraries(HelloWorldItkQt Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Gui Qt5::Core ${ITK_LIBRARIES})
```

Here you will find some more information:

[Qt5 and Cmake manual](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html)

[Similar SO problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875255/cmake-qt5-qt5-wrap-ui-not-generating-ui-header-files)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We have compiled the same project with cmake and were able to trace down the error thanks to cmakes output! Turns out one of the libs was included from an older ITK installation part of other software, because the folder structure where I compiled ITK was not correct.